HttpRequest with Microsoft Copilot Studio failing when assigning response to a variable
I've created a topic in Microsoft Copilot studio that makes an authenticated HTTP request to an external service.
Authenticate is the first step in that flow, and I am able to retrieve a valid access token from the OAuth provider I've configured.
When I make the request in postman using the access token obtained in copilot studio I'm able to successfully call the service and see the response.
The problem I'm having is that if I try to assign the response to a variable (to use in a later prompt) then copilot fails with "SystemError". The request does not fail (because it does not trigger an error) unless I attempt to assign the response to variable.
I've just set the variable type as any right now while I'm debugging this and it fails consistently with SystemError only when I assign the variable.
I checked the stacktrace in the browser and noticed this:

I've googled that error and came across a maybe completely unrelated github issue that suggests this may have to do with compression.
When I make the request in cURL, it will return me binary data unless I use the --compressed flag, so maybe there's something there?


tl;dr - microsoft bug
I've resolved this problem.
The server I was communicating with was:

Always returning gzipped content, regardless of accept-encoding in my HttpRequest header (bummer)
Was also returning the correct content-encoding header of gzip in it's response headers

Microsoft Copilot is failing to obey the content-encoding header on the response.
I determined this by spinning up a local server with a tunnel that acted as a proxy to my target server except my local server did not compress it's responses, and copilot was able to communicate with this local proxy server and save and surface the response without a problem.
